# jQuery select option hide not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown, cascadingdropdown

My cascading dropdown works fine, exactly how I want it to on a desktop device, however on mobile, the second option of the dropdown lets me choose any option, even those only meant for a different first dropdown input. Is there any way to fix this? I included a picture of what I am talking about and a link to my code.

html

```
<select name="category" id='dropdown1'>
    <option value="0" rel='start'>Select Model</option>
    <option value="1" rel="GFS">GFS</option>
    <option value="2" rel="NAM">NAM</option>
</select>

<select name="items" class="cascade", id="imgList" style='display:none'>
    <option value="" class='NAM'>Please select a timeframe</option>
    <option value="" class='GFS'>Please select a timeframe</option>
    <option value='.png' class="GFS">1-Day</option>
    <option value='.png' class="GFS">5-Days</option>
    <option value='.png' class="NAM">1-Day</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function() {

$('#imgList').css('display','block');

});

$(document).ready(function(){
var $cat = $('select[name=category]'),
$category = $('select[name=items]');

$cat.change(function(){
    
    var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
    rel = $this.attr('rel');
            
    // Hide all
    $category.find("option").hide();
      
    // Find all matching accessories
    // Show all the correct accesories
    // Select the first accesory
    $set = $category.find('option.' + rel);
    $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    
    });
});

        function setClass() {
            var img = document.getElementById("image");
            img.src = this.value;
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("imgList").onchange = setClass;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7t5rLa3h/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like hiding the `option` (`display:none`) on mobile browsers doesn't work. But you can disable and enable them like `options.attr('disable', true)`.

Alternatively, you can save a set of options in a variable and filter and re-populate the select later.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cat = $('select[name=category]'),
        $category = $('select[name=items]'),
        $options = $('select[name=items] option');
    
    $cat.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
            rel = $this.attr('rel'),
            $set = $options.filter('[data-category=' + rel + ']');
        $category.html($set)
        $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    });
});

$('#dropdown1').change(function() {
    $('#imgList').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Choose Model and Timeframe</h1>
<h2>

<select name="category" id='dropdown1'>
    <option value="0" rel='start'>Select Model</option>
    <option value="1" rel="GFS">GFS</option>
    <option value="2" rel="NAM">NAM</option>
</select>

<select name="items" class="cascade", id="imgList" style='display:none'>
    <option value="" data-category='NAM'>Please select a timeframe</option>
    <option value="" data-category='GFS'>Please select a timeframe</option>
    <option value='Model_Data/GFS/meteogram/trends/images/NYC/gfs_1day_temp.png' data-category="GFS">1-Day</option>
    <option value='Model_Data/GFS/meteogram/trends/images/NYC/gfs_5day_temp.png' data-category="GFS">5-Days</option>
    <option value='Model_Data/NAM/meteogram/images/1_day/NYC/nam_1day_temp.png' data-category="NAM">1-Day</option>
```

Comment: If you're looking for a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bsohrabi/zhnvfyw8/25/